# Storage permission issue for my wallpaper app in android marshmallow

Tags: android, permissions, file-permissions, android-wallpaper

Even after adding storage permission to my app I am unable to set wallpaper or download wallpaper (one function of my app) Its like wallpaper setting app. and unable to share the wallpaper.

Here is my piece of code which I did.

Please have a look on my code and tell me what's wrong with it.

If there is any solution plz explain me clearly step-by-step (I am New to android)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.saveitornot.wallit" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <permission android:name="com.saveitornot.wallit.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.saveitornot.wallit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>

    <application
        android:name=".app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FullScreenViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

FullscreenViewActivity.java

```
package com.saveitornot.wallit;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.saveitornot.wallit.app.AppController;
import com.saveitornot.wallit.picasa.model.Wallpaper;
import com.saveitornot.wallit.utils.Utils;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class FullScreenViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = FullScreenViewActivity.class
            .getSimpleName();
    public static final String TAG_SEL_IMAGE = "selectedImage";
    private Wallpaper selectedPhoto;
    private ImageView fullImageView;
    private LinearLayout llSetWallpaper, llDownloadWallpaper;
    private Utils utils;
    private ProgressBar pbLoader;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private int progressStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();



    private String licencseURL,licenseeURL = null;

    // Picasa JSON response node keys
    private static final String TAG_ENTRY = "entry",
            TAG_MEDIA_GROUP = "media$group",
            TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT = "media$content", TAG_IMG_URL = "url",
            TAG_IMG_WIDTH = "width", TAG_IMG_HEIGHT = "height";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image);

        fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);
        llSetWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSetWallpaper);
        llDownloadWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llDownloadWallpaper);
        pbLoader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoader);
        pbLoader.setIndeterminate(true);
        pbLoader.setMax(100);



        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id
                .coordinatorLayout);


        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        // layout click listeners
        llSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);

        // setting layout buttons alpha/opacity
        llSetWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);
        llDownloadWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);


        Intent i = getIntent();
        selectedPhoto = (Wallpaper) i.getSerializableExtra(TAG_SEL_IMAGE);

        // check for selected photo null
        if (selectedPhoto != null) {

            // fetch photo full resolution image by making another json request
            fetchFullResolutionImage();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Fetching image fullresolution json
     * */


    private void fetchFullResolutionImage() {
        String url = selectedPhoto.getPhotoJson();

        // show loader before making request
        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llSetWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        getSupportActionBar().hide();


        // volley's json obj request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Image full resolution json: "
                                + response.toString());
                try {
                    // Parsing the json response
                    JSONObject entry = response
                            .getJSONObject(TAG_ENTRY);

                    JSONArray mediacontentArry = entry.getJSONObject(
                            TAG_MEDIA_GROUP).getJSONArray(
                            TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT);

                    JSONObject mediaObj = (JSONObject) mediacontentArry
                            .get(0);

                    String fullResolutionUrl = mediaObj
                            .getString(TAG_IMG_URL);

                    // image full resolution widht and height
                    final int width = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_WIDTH);
                    final int height = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_HEIGHT);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Full resolution image. url: "
                            + fullResolutionUrl + ", w: " + width
                            + ", h: " + height);

                    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController
                            .getInstance().getImageLoader();

                    // We download image into ImageView instead of
                    // NetworkImageView to have callback methods
                    // Currently NetworkImageView doesn't have callback
                    // methods

                    ///
                    progressStatus = 0;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            while (progressStatus<100){
                                progressStatus += 1;
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        pbLoader.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                    }
                                });
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                }catch (InterruptedException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();

                    ///

                    imageLoader.get(fullResolutionUrl,
                            new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(
                                        VolleyError arg0) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                            getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(
                                        ImageLoader.ImageContainer response,
                                        boolean arg1) {
                                    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                                        // load bitmap into imageview

                                        fullImageView
                                                .setImageBitmap(response
                                                        .getBitmap());
                                        adjustImageAspect(width, height);


                                        // hide loader and show set &
                                        // download buttons
                                        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        llSetWallpaper
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        llDownloadWallpaper
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        getSupportActionBar().show();

                                    }
                                }
                            });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                // unable to fetch wallpapers
                // either google username is wrong or
                // devices doesn't have internet connection
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        // Remove the url from cache
        AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);

        // Disable the cache for this url, so that it always fetches updated
        // json
        jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

    /**
     * Adjusting the image aspect ration to scroll horizontally, Image height
     * will be screen height, width will be calculated respected to height
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void adjustImageAspect(int bWidth, int bHeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        if (bWidth == 0 || bHeight == 0)
            return;

        int sHeight = 0;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            sHeight = size.y;
        } else {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            sHeight = display.getHeight();
        }

        int new_width = (int) Math.floor((double) bWidth * (double) sHeight
                / (double) bHeight);
        params.width = new_width;
        params.height = sHeight;

        Log.d(TAG, "Fullscreen image new dimensions: w = " + new_width
                + ", h = " + sHeight);

        fullImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    /**
     * View click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            // button Download Wallpaper tapped
            case R.id.llDownloadWallpaper:
                utils.saveImageToSDCard(bitmap, coordinatorLayout);
                break;
            // button Set As Wallpaper tapped
            case R.id.llSetWallpaper:
                utils.setAsWallpaper(bitmap, coordinatorLayout);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fullscreen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void gotoURL(String url)
    {
        Uri uri =  Uri.parse(url);
        Intent goToWebsite = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
        // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
        int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
            flags |= Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT;
        }
        else
        {
            //noinspection deprecation
            flags |= Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET;
        }
        goToWebsite.addFlags(flags);

        try {
            startActivity(goToWebsite);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:

                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_set_as_wallpaper:
                utils.setAsWallpaper(bitmap, coordinatorLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_download:
                utils.saveImageToSDCard(bitmap, coordinatorLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_share:
                utils.shareImage(bitmap, coordinatorLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_report:
                utils.reportImage(bitmap);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

}
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
package com.saveitornot.wallit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.saveitornot.wallit.app.AppController;
import com.saveitornot.wallit.utils.PrefManager;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    private PrefManager pref;
    private TextView txtGoogleUsername, txtNoOfGridColumns, txtGalleryName;
    private Button btnSave;
    private Button btnClearCache;
    private Button btnCacheSize;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        txtGoogleUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGoogleUsername);
        txtNoOfGridColumns = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNoOfColumns);
        txtGalleryName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGalleryName);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnClearCache = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClearCache);
        btnCacheSize  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCacheSize);

        pref = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.action_settings));

        // Display edittext values stored in shared preferences
        // Google username
        txtGoogleUsername.setText(pref.getGoogleUserName());

        // Number of grid columns
        txtNoOfGridColumns.setText(String.valueOf(pref.getNoOfGridColumns()));

        // Gallery name
        txtGalleryName.setText(pref.getGalleryName());

        // Save settings button click listener
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Validating the data before saving to shared preferences
                // validate google username
                String googleUsername = txtGoogleUsername.getText().toString()
                        .trim();
                if (googleUsername.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString(R.string.toast_enter_google_username),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                // validate number of grid columns
                String no_of_columns = txtNoOfGridColumns.getText().toString()
                        .trim();
                if (no_of_columns.length() == 0 || !isInteger(no_of_columns)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString(R.string.toast_enter_valid_grid_columns),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                // validate gallery name
                String galleryName = txtGalleryName.getText().toString().trim();
                if (galleryName.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString(R.string.toast_enter_gallery_name),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                // Check for setting changes
                if (!googleUsername.equalsIgnoreCase(pref.getGoogleUserName())
                        || !no_of_columns.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(pref
                        .getNoOfGridColumns()))
                        || !galleryName.equalsIgnoreCase(pref.getGalleryName())) {
                    // User changed the settings
                    // save the changes and launch SplashScreen to initialize
                    // the app again
                    pref.setGoogleUsername(googleUsername);
                    pref.setNoOfGridColumns(Integer.parseInt(no_of_columns));
                    pref.setGalleryName(galleryName);

                    // start the app from SplashScreen
                    Intent i = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,
                            SplashActivity.class);
                    // Clear all the previous activities
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    // user not modified any values in the form
                    // skip saving to shared preferences
                    // just go back to previous activity
                    onBackPressed();
                }

            }
        });


        btnClearCache.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppController.getInstance().clearCache();
            }
        });

        btnCacheSize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppController.getInstance().getCacheSize();
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean isInteger(String input) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(input);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean ifPermissionReady(){

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            System.out.println("req write storage permission*****");
            checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Constant.PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        System.out.println("onRequestPermissionsResult******");

        //onStateNotSaved();
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case Constant.PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:{
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Do something
                } else {
                    System.out.println("---> permission denied");
                    //Do something
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

marshmallow require developer to acquire permission during runtime. Try above code.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer..
can you please tell me where to add this code (i mean which class, below what line)

Comment: right before you need to use the permission. eg. if you ask user to click a button, and perform a read/write storage. then when they click the button, u call ifPermissionReady, only the function return true, you proceed the read/write.

Comment: btw, also check other permissions that may require you to do the same. If not it may either not perform the action you want it to do if you are lucky or it will crash your app. eg(read contact or camera permission will crash the app if you did not ask permission in advance)

Comment: getActivity() , WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are getting hilighted in Red color

Comment: Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE should be there Manifest is in package android;   but Constant.PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE you need to declare.  I just create a Constant.java                                                           public static final int PERMISSION_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICE = 101;
 //public static final int PERMISSION_GET_CONTACT = 102;
 public static final int PERMISSION_READ_CONTACTS = 103;
 public static final int PERMISSION_CAMERA = 104;
 public static final int PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 105;

Comment: sorry for the mess. the constants just a number for you to refer back when you check in onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: Still getActivity() is showing error as cannot resolve method

Comment: your r extending AppCompatActivity, use this to replace getActivity(), ie  ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  ......

Comment: Still no improvment.... plz tell where to insert the code exactly in which file

I have file like 
FragmentDrawer,
FullScreenActivity,
GridFragment,
MainActivity,
SplashActivity,
Settings Activity,

Comment: Thank you. Finally i got perfect solution