# Why did my permissions suddenly disapper on an Android app I am writing?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I've been working on an Android App.  It does recording and writes to the local storage area.  Here are the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And in the middle of debugging I lost the permissions on the tablet itself.  I had to go to Settings->Applications->(my app)->App Permissions and turn them on myself.  Both Microphone and Storage had their sliders set to off.

While I am up and running now, I would love to know how this might have happened so I can prevent it from happening again.

Any clues as to where I should look?

Thank you,

Comment: What android version you are using?

Comment: If you are in android version 6.0, it requires you to request permission during runtime. Added [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626882/storage-permission-issue-for-my-wallpaper-app-in-android-marshmallow/38626960#38626960

Comment: If your device runs Android 6.0, you need request for some special permission, as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 1):

**Runtime permissions demo.**

```
public class MyDevIDS extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 123;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (CheckPermission(MyDevIDS.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // you have permission go ahead
                createApplicationFolder();
            } else {
                // you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
                RequestPermission(MyDevIDS.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

            switch (permsRequestCode) {

                case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // you have permission go ahead
                        createApplicationFolder();
                    } else {
                        // you do not have permission show toast.
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                    Permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                        Permission)) {
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                            new String[]{Permission},
                            Code);
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean CheckPermission(Context context, String Permission) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android 6+, some permissions like Storage aren't granted without explicit request at runtime.

If you uninstall and reinstall the app or simply clear the app data, the permissions be revoked. That may explain your situation.

Comment: Is there something I can do that will avoid this?  Afterall the first time I did this, the permissions were added via my app (the AndroidManifest file).  Is there some other way I should be granting the apps to avoid this in the future?

Comment: no, you have to write the permissions into your manifest AND ask for them at runtime when needed, as shown in the runtime demo post.